# Xamarin Forms and Asterisk integration

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asterisk-ari

I need to develop an application with Xamarin Forms. The application must connect to Asterisk Server. I tried to use `AsterNet.ARI` library but I have some compatibility error on Droid and iOS projects.

> **Error   NU1202**    The package AsterNET.ARI 1.2.1 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)/win-x86. The package
>   AsterNET.ARI 1.2.1 support: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   **Error   NU120**2    The package AsterNET.ARI 1.2.1 is not compatible with monoandroid80 (Monoandroid,Version=v8.0). The package AsterNET.ARI
>   1.2.1 support: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

Maybe I must to use another library, but I don't have any idea. Anyone can help me? What type of library can I use?

Comment: This is a very vague question, image if someone asked you that on the street. Would you have any idea what they are talking about? I'm going with down-vote and close until you can actually describe what the problem is and concise way

Comment: there's another similar question and other people aren't rude like you!

Comment: Its not that i'm rude, i see 1000s of questions a day and and this was of very low quality, and that was saying something. however at least you pasted your errors, its a good start

Comment: I guess you should add that reference to your **PCL** instead. Make sure it targets at least .NET 4.5. You can then add a wrapper class for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it seems there is no support for the target framework, I would suggest:

- try changing either the framework or the library
- trying to use Netsockets for communication with AMI or managing everything on the ARI.

Good luck!